# Default angularjs ng-option when data is returned from a service

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

The normal solutions I've seen for this so far haven't been working. My controller returns the list of options from a service and populates the select element without any problems but I haven't been able to set a default value. The closest I've come returned an error: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined` with the code `$scope.new_account.account_type = $scope.new_account.account_type[0];`. With that error I assumed that the object just wasn't ready yet so I used a resolve to return my service data.

```
.when('/accounts/new/', {
    controller: function ($scope, accountTypes) {
        $scope.accountTypes = accountTypes;
        $scope.new_account.account_type = accountTypes[0];
    },
    resolve: {
        accountTypes: function (AccountService) {
            return AccountService.getAccountTypes();
        }
    }
})
```

But this, along with similar solutions, have had no affect. The select element gets populated but the default option is blank. I would prefer to set a default option rather than use a "please select" default with the `?` value.

I've also tried

```
controller: function ($scope, AccountService) {
    $scope.accountTypes = AccountService.getAccountTypes();
}
```

With various implementations of $scope and ng-init...

```
<select ng-model="new_account.account_type" ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in accountTypes" 
    ng-init="new_account.account_type='General'">

    ng-init="new_account.account_type.name='General'">

    ng-init="new_account.account_type=0">
```

Any thoughts to help set a default value for this?

As requested, the accountTypes returns `[{"id":1, "name":"General"}, {"id":2, "name":"Super"}, {"id":3, "name":"Trial"}`

Comment: Can you post Fiddle/Plunker?

Comment: Or post `$scope.accountTypes` model

Comment: it's a tricky but it should work :)

Comment: var data =  AccountService.getAccountTypes();
$scope.mydefault = data.shift();
$scope.accountTypes = data;
<select ng-model="new_account.account_type" ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in accountTypes" >
<option value="{{mydefault.id}}">{{mydefault.name}}</option>
</select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="fessCntrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="selectedItem.name as selectedItem.name for selectedItem in values"></select>selectedItem: {{selectedItem}}
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, Data, $timeout) {
    Data.loadData().then(function (result) {

        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.values = result;
            $scope.selectedItem = $scope.values[0].name;
        }, 2000); // dummy, to simulate delay 
    },

    function (result) {
        alert("Error: No data returned");
    });
});
fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope', 'Data', '$timeout'];


fessmodule.service('Data', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
    this.values = [{
        "id": 1,
            "name": "General"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "name": "Super"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "name": "Trial"
    }];

     this.loadData = function() {
     this.deferred = $q.defer();
     this.deferred.resolve(this.values);

      return this.deferred.promise;
    };   
}]);
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/608/)</kbd>

Sounds like you have problem `AccountService`. Above code with service is work

However if I'll write service by this way:

```
fessmodule.service('Data', ['$resource', '$q', function ($resource, $q) {
    this.values = [{
        "id": 1,
            "name": "General"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "name": "Super"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "name": "Trial"
    }];


    this.factory = {
        loadData: function (selectedSubject) {
            this.deferred = $q.defer();
            this.deferred.resolve(this.values);

            return this.deferred.promise;
        }
    }
    return this.factory;
}]);
```

I get error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/609/)

Comment: Like I said: `ng-init="new_account.account_type=0"` didn't work

Comment: I don't see `$scope.accountTypes` please post it or `AccountService`

Comment: No, no go. Your method doesn't throw any errors but that initial select option is still blank. Thanks for the input though. I'm beginning to think that this may be an issue of implementing the controller on the $routeProvider. Which I thought a resolve would solve. If I have time later I'll put a plunkr together to better demonstrate what's going on.

Comment: `initial select option is still blank.`  what do you mean? when I open Fiddle, 1st element is selected

Comment: Exactly that. It works in the Fiddle. I'm pretty sure your method was one of the first I even tried. Everything says this should work. But the select is always generated with a default blank option. Which leads me to believe it's a bug with $routeProvider and creating the controller from there.

Comment: Like tennisgent says you get the promise and, lets say, after 1 sec the object is created. I can add in fiddle timeout to simulate delay and loader. What you think

Comment: Man, I had already put this aside to work on other things. Tried your $timeout suggestion and still nothing. Then I realized I was trying to inject $timeout in the app.config instead of the route's controller. Works great. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your `AccountService.getAccountTypes()` returns a promise, based on your controller code.  So, you need to wait until the promise is resolved before setting your default value.  Without seeing the exact code for the AccountService, I can't give the exact answer, but I'll try my best given what we know.

First, forget the `resolve:` bit and just do your GET in the controller, like this:

```
controller: function ($scope, AccountService) {
    // if your getAccountTypes accepts a success callback, do this:
    $scope.accountTypes = AccountService.getAccountTypes(function(){
        $scope.new_account.account_type = $scope.accountTypes[0];
    });
    // and if it doesn't accept a callback, do this:
    $scope.accountTypes = AccountService.getAccountTypes();
    $scope.$watch('accountTypes', function(newValue){
         if(newValue && newValue.length){
             $scope.new_account.account_type = newValue[0];
         }
    });
    // (but obviously you shouldn't need both of the above options, just one or the other)
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense and fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but neither had positive results. The first is just like Maxim's and doesn't update the select. Mind you, I can console.log it just fine. It just doesn't bind to the select. The second method comes back as undefined (using $watch instead of watch).

Comment: Ok. I added one extra line to the `$watch` function (thanks for the syntax correction), try that and see if it works...  If not, please post your code for your `AccountService` service and we'll see if we can't debug through that.

Comment: Still a blank initial option. No errors though. I doubt you'll find anything in my AccountService. Just an $http.get. AccountService... return { getAccountTypes: function() { return http.get(...).then(function(result) { return results.data; }); }};

Comment: Your method didn't throw any errors but had the same non result. Didn't provide a default value. The service itself is just returns an $http.get(). Nothing special.